# rotating View in angle?

Tags: iphone

i want to rotate my UIview to particular angle and stop that rotation in that angle.any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a UIView, change its `.transform` property.

```
theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 25 / 180);
```

Use UIView animation block to animate the rotation, as usual.